# separate file output IN PYTHON

Tags: python

I have a python code, which reads several xml files and output them at the same time, I want to separate the output of each file, how to do it please?

```
import glob
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
path = "./resources/test_out/"

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xml")): # ouvrir et lire tout le repertoire XML
    with open(filename) as open_file:
        content = open_file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

    for link in soup.find_all('p'):  # recuperer les  paragraphes
        print(link.text)
```

Comment: Put something like `print("*** READING FROM", filename, "***")` at the top of the outer `for` loop, perhaps?  If that's not what you want, please explain what you mean by "separate the output".

Comment: It's not clear what you want your output to look like. What does "separate" mean when you are printing to the console? Do you want `print(filename, link.txt)` as a solution?